# How can I create a `tf.data.Dataset` for a `tf.keras` model that accepts multiple inputs of various shapes?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a `tf.keras` model that needs to accept multiple inputs of multiple shapes. My goal is to build it in such a way that I can train and evaluate it easily using its `fit` and `evaluate` API.

So far, the model is built as follows:

```
class MultipleLSTM(Model):
    def __init__(self, lstm_dims=128, name='multi_lstm', **kwargs):
        super(MultipleLSTM, self).__init__(name=name)

        # initialize encoders for every attribute
        self.encoders = []
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.encoders.append(self._create_encoder(lstm_dims, value))

        # initialize the rest of the network layers
        self.concat = Concatenate(axis=0)
        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(6, 4, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x_1 = self.encoders[0](inputs[0])
        x_2 = self.encoders[1](inputs[1])
        x_3 = self.encoders[2](inputs[2])
        x_4 = self.encoders[3](inputs[3])

        x = self.concat([x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4])

        # fix the shape for the convolutions
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=3)

        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        x = self.out(x)

        return x

    def _create_encoder(self, lstm_dims, conf):
        with tf.name_scope(conf['name']) as scope:
            encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(name=scope)
            encoder.add(Embedding(conf['vocab'], 
                                  conf['embed_dim'], 
                                  input_length=conf['input_length']))
            encoder.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_dims)))
        return encoder
```

There are four different inputs, text sentences of different lengths, that are fed to four different `Embedding` and `LSTM` layers (`encoders`). Then the outputs of those layers are concatenated to create a single tensor that is forwarded to the subsequent layers.

To train this network, I'm passing as input a list of lists, for the different tokenized sentences. The label is just number, 0 or 1 (binary classification). For example, an input could be:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [2, 3, 5],
     [3, 5, 6, 7],
     [1, 5, 7]]
y = 0
```

For now, I have implemented a custom loop that takes such input and trains the network:

```
def train(data, model, loss_fn, optimizer, metric, epochs=10, print_every=50):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print(f'Start of epoch {epoch+1}')

        for step, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(data):
            with GradientTape() as tape:
                output = model(x_batch)
                loss = loss_fn(y_batch, output)

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
            metric(loss)

            if step % print_every == 0:
                print(f'step {step}: mean loss = {metric.result()}')
```

But this prevents me from exploiting the easy to use tf.keras API, to `fit` and `evaluate` the model or even split the dataset into train and test sets. Thus, the question is: How can I create a `tf.data.Dataset` from such x's and y's and pass it to the `fit` function of `tf.keras`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functional api of keras to do so. Here is the link of the keras documentation on multi input, output if you want : [Multi-input and multi-output models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the different inputs as a list and fit and evaluate methods.

```
model.fit([X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1]], y_train, ...)
```